# Different version of python installed

Tags: python

[image]

have different version of python installed to my Mac, when I opened vs studio code it said I am using version 2.7.16 while the terminal for my Mac said its 3.8.5. How am I going to config that?

Comment: Python 2 is outdated. Use Python 3!

Comment: Don't use Python 2.X - it's no longer maintained.

Comment: And python 2 isn't a part of MacOS OS (i.e like Ubuntu)?

Comment: @CutePoison Not sure what you mean. You should not remove Python 2 from the system.

Comment: it looks like you have python2 installed in the base environment ( mostly a conda environment). you can change that in the virtual environment of the IDE by changing your project properties.

Comment: you can specifically use python3 or python3.8 or python3.x if you have multiple python3 installed. Or you can use the full path to the python version you want to use.

Comment: @Triplee That was my point - you might risk breaking stuff when removing Python2 (Ubuntu 18.04 uses it for the system for instance, thus removing it on Ubuntu fucks it up)